# Sort "array" of mixed data type in C

Tags: c

I have a continuous block of memory, where the first N bytes all contain objects of type A and the remaining bytes contain elements of type B.  So for example, I might have 120 objects of type A followed by 40 objects of type B.

Type A and type B are both structures with different sizes, but both have an integer member "index" which is what I want to sort on.  Basically I want to end up with an array that is sorted on index and I currently have one which is sorted on data type.  Ideally, I'd like to end up with it sorted on index, then by type, so something like

```
Index==1 elements | Index==2 elements | ... | Index==L elements
Type A   | Type B | Type A  |  Type B | ... | Type A| Type B
```

The only thing I've come up with so far is to sort the type A and type B blocks separately by index and then use memcopy to shuffle things around so they look like above.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: Just to be sure, what is the type of your array? `char*`? This isn't looking pretty.

Comment: This description has had alignment issue alarms going off like mad in my head.

Comment: They're two different types.  It's not really an array as such, rather its two arrays that sit next to one another in memory.  Neither are a simple type like int,float,char etc. That is, both types are structs that I have defined.

Comment: Can you just use another array of pointers to objects, and then sort the pointers?

Comment: Can you use C++ std containers or do you want to stick to pure C?

Comment: @Konstantin I don't think it is worth switching languages for only that one thing...

Comment: @glglgl Well, the transition from C to C++ might consist of a simple `#include <vector>`, depending on the rest of the code and the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pointers as suggested, you might want to use a struct consisting of type and pointer (the latter even as a union of two different pointers). In this case, you can easily distinguish which type the objects are - unless they nevertheless have the ID field at the same place.

So suppose you have

```
struct typeA {
    int whatever;
    int id;
}

struct typeB {
    double whatever;
    int id;
}
```

you are bitten and have to do as I stated:

```
struct typptr {
    enum type { typ_A, typ_B } type;
    union {
        struct typeA * Aptr;
        struct typeB * Bptr;
    }
}

int getID(struct typptr t)
{
    if (t.type == typ_A) {
        return (t.Aptr)->id * 2;
    } else {
        return (t.Bptr)->id * 2 + 1; // have B always sorted after A...
    }
}
```

This way you can easily write a cmp function for qsort in order to sort the `struct typptr`s.

If the types are "shaped similiarly", such as

```
struct typeA {
    int id;
    int whatever;
}

struct typeB {
    int id;
    double whatever;
}
```

i.e. have the `id` field at the start, things are easier (but I don't know if this is portable) as you can always cast to one of them and read out the `id` field. So you only need an array of pointers and can omit the type field.

Answer (score 2):

How is the original array set up?  Mixing different types in the same array seems like a bad idea.  Is there a reason you need to have them in the same array?

If they must be in the same array you might want to use a union.  Something like

```
enum myType { A, B };
struct typeA { myType type; int key; ... data ... }
struct typeB { myType type; int key; ... data ... }
union myTypes { typeA myA; typeB myB }
myTypes data[128];
```

You can now use the [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function from the C library.

Another option would be to use a separate array of pointers to the objects and then sort that auxilary array.  You would still need some kind of type field at the beginning of each struct though.

Comment: The problem with using a union is that typeB is much larger than typeA and so I'd end up with an array of mostly padding.  A separate array of pointers might work but I can see that maybe I need to rethink the code around it to avoid having to do this at all.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1356855 Then I think using a separate array of pointers is the better solution.  You can still use the C library qsort fuction.  But, yeah, I think rethinking the underlying problem and finding a better overall solution might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

There's important information in your later comment - the types aren't initially mixed.
If so, you could run a sort phase on each array part individually (quicksort or any other method you'd like), and then do a final phase of merge-sort between the two arrays (assuming you can spare the additional space)

that's still NlogN + N = NlogN